# Project Euler's Multiples of 3 and 5 - Problem - Python

Tags: python, math

I just tried to solve [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) in Project Euler but I don't understand why this code is not working and the output answer is wrong.
**QUESTION** - If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

correct answer = `233168`
My output =`266333`

```
a = 0
for x in range(0,1000,3):
    a = a + x
for x in range(0,1000,5):
    a = a + x
print(a)
```

Comment: Because you count the multiples of both 3 and 5 twice, e.g. `15` . Add a loop for subtracting such values e.g. `for x in range(0,1000,15): a = a - x`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh thanks man for helping

Comment: Given the relatively small number of multiples, you could use a set: `sum({*range(3,1000,3),*range(5,1000,5)})` so that you count each multiple only once.  you could also subtract the multiples of 15 that are doubled: `sum(range(3,1000,3))+sum(range(5,1000,5))-sum(range(15,1000,15))`

Answer (score 1):

[ProjectEuler #1](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/problem)

```
def f(x):                               
    n1, n2, n3 = x//3, x//5, x//15
    return 3*(n1)*(n1+1)//2+5*(n2)*(n2+1)//2-15*(n3)*(n3+1)//2
for i in range(int(input())):                  
    print(f(int(input())-1))
```

Here `x//3` gives `int(x/3)` similarly for `x//5` and `x//15`

As `LCM(3,5)=15`

`Σi = n(n+1)/2`

**answer= sum of multiples of 3 + sum of multiples of 5 - sum of multiples of 15.**

corresponds to a solution of ProjectEulerProblem #1

- Note: My intention of sharing codes on StackOverflow is to let people know that a given problem could be solved in many ways.

  As it's always a difficult for one to pass  all cases due to timeError.

**Do not use as an answer but learn.**

Answer (score 0):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159737/project-eulers-multiples-of-3-and-5-problem-python/61159887#comment108196329_61159737) by [Devesh Kumar Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8591431/devesh-kumar-singh) solves the question:

> Because you count the multiples of both 3 and 5 twice, e.g. `15` . Add a loop for subtracting such values e.g. `for x in range(0,1000,15): a = a - x`

Answer (score 0):

You are overcounting the multiples of 15. One way to fix this would be to have just one loop which checks if the number is a multiple of 3 or 5.

```
solution = 0
for i in range(1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        solution += i
print(solution)
```